# Java/ImageIO Validate format before reading the entire file?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm developing a Web application that will let users upload images. 
My concern is the file´s size, specially if they are invalid formats.

I'm wondering if there´s a way in java (or a third party library) to check the allowed files formats (jpg, gif and png) before reading the entire file.

Comment: what are you using for handling uploads? commons file-upload?

Comment: actually I'm using icefaces, and I get a more abstract call when the files is already loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to support only a few types of images you can start by (up)loading the image and at some point use the first few bytes to check wether you wish to continue the upload.

Quite a lot of image formats can be recognized by the first few bytes, the [magic number](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html). If the number matches you don't know whether the file is valid of course, but it may be used to match extension and magic number to prevent is really does not correspond at all.

Have a look at [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) to check out some Java which checks mime-types. Do read the docs or source to check whether any given method requires the entire file, or can operate on the first few bytes. I've not used those libraries :)

Also check out [this page](http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2006/12/file-type-mime-detection.html) which also lists some java libraries, and some papers on which detection is based.

Don't forget to put in some feedback if you managed to find something you like!

Comment: great tip! I'm going to check this. Please let me know if you find something relevant

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3rd party libraries. The code you have to write is simple.

At the point you are handling your uploads, filter the files by their extension. This isn't perfect, but will account for most of the cases.

However, this would mean files are already uploaded to the server. You can use a bit of javascript on the client-side to perform the same operation - check whether the value of the file-upload component contains an allowed file type - `.jpg`, `.png`, etc.

Comment: as you said this isn't going to be "perfect. I'm a bit concern about malicious user trying to upload a wrong file

Comment: @Dani Cricco you can't stop that. Even if there is a library that checks the headers of a file to see if it is a jpeg, the malicious users can fake these headers and do their things anyway. But these will be a rare case, trust me.

Comment: I'm currently creating a BufferedImage with ImageIO.read. If the file is invalid then the ImageIO.red should fail. The problem is that I don't want to read the whole file into a BufferedImage, because it might be very big

Comment: @Dani: I don't have a good solution for your requirement (and your points are indeed valid), but ImageIO.read won't necessarily suffice either. ImageIO may accept malicious images and may also reject valid files. I've seen JPEG files with strange colour profiles, which are in theory correct, but are rejected by ImageIO in Java 5 and accepted in Java 6.

Comment: Checking for file extension is a TOTALLY insufficient method, esp. on a website where users are going to upload pics!!! I worked at such a site and the site requirement was that uploaded pics were restricted to jpegs for obvious disk space reasons. You'd be amazed how many members of the general public think that changing the file extension to .jpg converts the file to jpeg type.

Comment: if you want to restrict disk usage, then you can limit the upload size :) Restricting the file type is not as efficient, as you noted

Answer (score 0):

```
function extensionsOkay(fval) {
    var extension = new Array();

    extension[0] = ".png";
    extension[1] = ".gif";
    extension[2] = ".jpg";
    extension[3] = ".jpeg";
    extension[4] = ".bmp";

    // No other customization needed.
    var thisext = fval.substr(fval.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
    for(var i = 0; i < extension.length; i++) {
        if(thisext == extension[i]) { 
            $('#support-documents').hide();
            return true; }
    }

    // show client side error message
    $('#span.failed').show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: (Some months after...sorry but I deal with the same prob) what is the variable fval? the file? what function (eg. getParameter) do you use in order to take this variable? with simple 'getParameter' it does not work. Thank you.